# Visualise grouped line plots in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, pyspark, seaborn

I have this `DF`(sample) and I am using PySpark in Databricks. I would like to have line plot `DATE` vs `BALANCE` but for each `ID` in one single frame.

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|         DATE|      BALANCE|              ID|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   2021-07-01|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-02|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-03|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-04|     81289.62|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-05|     81385.62|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-02|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-03|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-04|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-05|     81324.28|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-06|     81329.28|         Bz3838J|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

I can plot for one single `ID` but I have more than 10000 unique `ID`s. How can I visualise multiple line plots segmented based on `ID`. Also, Is there any smart ways to visualise the `DF` all together?

```
DF_single.toPandas().plot.line(x='DATE', y='BALANCE')
```

[image: DATE vs BALANCE for single ID]

Note: Image is for a particular `ID` from the actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot your pandas DataFrame in order to turn `ID` labels into separate columns containing, like:

```
(
    DF_single
    .toPandas()
    .pivot_table(index='DATE',columns='ID',values='BALANCE')
    .plot()
)
```

the `pivot_table` function aggregates the values passed in `values` so if your DataFrame has more than one value for each `DATE`/`ID`, you can choose the appropriate aggregation function and pass it through the parameter `aggfunc` (e.g.: `aggfunc=np.mean` or `aggfunc='mean'` - the default is `'mean'`). From the way you posed your question, you probably have only one value per `DATE`/`ID`, so the aggfunc doesn't really matter in your case, but it's important to understand what `pivot_table` is doing.

Also, pandas's `plot` function by default plots lines, and it uses columns as different series and the index as the x-axis, so there's no need to specify anything else =)

You can check the doc for the `pivot_table` function here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Hope that helps! Good luck =)

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful for getting the sense. However, I have 2.6 million `ID`s and above code kept running for hours literally. Do you know any alternative way to visualise even at least 100,000 unique data points?